# Python: Add elements from 1D array to nD array with Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, element

I have 2 ND arrays:

```
x = zeros(shape=(N,9)); vx = zeros(shape=(N,9))
```

I also have 2 1D arrays:

```
x0 = [] # array with 9 elements
vx0 = [] # array with 9 elements
```

I want the following output:

```
x: [[ x0[0]  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.][ x0[1]  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]... ]etc
vx : [[ vx[0]  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.][ vx[1]  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]...]etc
```

I tried:

```
for k in range(8):
    x[k:0] = x[k:0] + x0[k]
    vx[k:0] = vx[k:0] + vx0[k]

print x
```

x[0] will be the first array in the x-array.  x[0:0] will be the first element in the first list in the x-array

I get following output:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
...] etc
```

But x0 contains floats different from 0.

Can someone help me with my issue or point me in the right direction?

EDIT: I used the Numpy module

Comment: You forgot to specify the language; I assume this is python. What do you expect `x[0:0]` and `x[3:0]` (etc.) to be in your loop over `k`?

Comment: x[0] will be the first array in the x-array.  x[0:0] will be the first element in the first list in the x-array

Comment: `zeros` are not builtin. Seems you are using numpy, right?

Comment: yes correct, I used the numpy module.

Comment: x[0:0] is empty (nothing), not the first element. Correct one is x[0, 0]

Comment: And where that `8` comes from? Is it a value of `N`? Or did you intentionally take `9 - 1` for some reason?

Comment: Thank you. I got it correct now, but what is x[0:k] then?

Comment: Rows of `x` whose index from 0 to `k-1`

Comment: Yeah, it should be 9. It's just the length of x0 and x

Comment: yeah, true, I remembered it now. Thank you :D

Comment: How do I give rep points to you?

Comment: Don't edit the answer into the question, and don't edit the title with "SOLVED" and other things. If @Jeon wants to get rep for this trivial fix, they can add an answer which you can accept. If Jeon doesn't want to, you should just delete your question as it is unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: yes, sire Thank you